Twilio Client SDK for Python without Web UI for Raspberry Pi Project
I’m working on a device using a Raspberry Pi that will allow children and individuals with disabilities to make phone calls through physical buttons. I have some experience with Twilio for handling phone calls, but I’ve never developed a client-side application before.
My challenge is that the device will not have a web interface. I’ve seen the Twilio Client JS SDK, but it seems tailored for web-based applications. Is there an SDK or API that I can use with Python to create a Twilio client without relying on a web interface? Any guidance or examples would be appreciated!

Are you able to find a solution?
